# What does this error message mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

In C++, on this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/visualc/bb985511.aspx

I downloaded the code sample and went to Debug and it came up with a messagebox with 2 textboxes in it and told me to specify the executable file to debug. So I did, and then I clicked browse, but there is NO executable because the stupid thing hasn't created one yet.

I'm using visual studio c++ 2008; what's up with that weird message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message generally comes up when you try to debug into a system DLL or 3rd party code.  Set a breakpoint with F9 and hit F5 and see if stop in your code in debug.  Also make sure you are building the debug version.

happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

That project builds a DLL.  If you're going to debug a DLL, you need to provide a .EXE that loads the DLL.